# How Clean Flutter/bin folder cache

Tags: flutter, caching, apk, release, code-cleanup

Is there any way to clean up flutter/bin folder cache? or older app release apk without opening an individual app and writing the command flutter build clean?

I just want to free up space from the flutter folder.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can run `rm -rf ~/flutter/bin/cache` in the terminal to clear the Flutter bin cache.

Comment: does it affect flutter performance?

Comment: Only in the first run. Not in the performance of the Flutter app, but in its build time.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn [this command](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/cmd/pub-cache#clearing-the-global-system-cache) perform the cleaning you desire?

```
$ dart pub cache clean
```

Comment: No it's just remove cache at USER/USER_NAME/.pub-cache.

Comment: Still Flutter/bin folder size is 2.5 GB